# Informatica, [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified error when connecting to SQL Server database

Tags: odbc, informatica, informatica-powercenter, dsn

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database from Informatica. I want to Enable the Application intent to 'READONLY'. I have tried creating USER DSNs/SYSTEM DSNs (Both 32 & 64 bit) but still getting the below error:

> Severity  Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message ERROR   7/27/2022
> 8:39:36 AM    NODE01_SEIMDBINFDEV2    READER_1_1_1    RR_4036 Error connecting
> to database [ [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not
> found and no default driver specified SQLSTATE: IM002
>
> Database driver error... Function Name: Connect Database driver
> error... Function Name : Connect Database Error: Failed to connect to
> database using user [user_name] and connection string [ODBC System DSN
> Name].].

I am able to test the connection in ODBC Data Source Administrator.
Please find the attachment for Informatica Relational Connection that I have created in Workflow Manager.

[image]

Comment: where is the infa server located ? is it in the same box from where you posted this screenshot?

Comment: This was the silly mistake at my end. I realised that DSN should be created on the server where Informatica is installed the moment I read your comment. 
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note you need to setup this connection in informatica server as well.

If your infa server is windows, you have to setup ODBC system DSN properly. give it a name without spaces  like my_sql_serv_conn.

Then use this connection name in place of connection string.

If your infa server is UNIX,  we need to set two odbc related parameters in unix/linux users bash profile.

```
INFA_HOME=/opt/infa
ODBCINI= $INFA_HOME/ODBC7.1/odbc.ini
ODBCINST=$INFA_HOME/ODBC7.1/odbcinst.ini
```

Now, i feel like, your unix/linux user is not able to reach this location or they arent getting exported properly.
Login using the unix/linux user thats running informatica.

Then use `more $ODBCINI` to see if it has read permission.
Do same for ODBCINST.
Use `ssgodbc` tool to check connectivity to your mssql server DB.

Comment: This was the silly mistake at my end. I realised that DSN should be created on the server where Informatica is installed the moment I read your comment. 
Thank You